# ReportBuilder doesnt show QueryDesigner view with tables and fields

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have ReportBuilder and it doesnt show QueryDesigner view with tables and fields which can help me to generate SQL Query directly. Instead I need to write the SQL Query on my own. I saw some tutorials where the view was as in screenshot. However I get a different view . Any inputs on this? It is so time consuming to build queries manually . I have to use Report Builder specifically for a client
[image]

[image]

Comment: I've never seen an issue with the query designer - though I rarely use it (I use SSMS to make a query). Is your data source working - Does a simple select from a known table work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I am new to Report builder and have to learn it for some legacy tasks and I must say it has different approach than PowerBI or Tableau .Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically got answer for this question . Query designer in Report Builder is not available for Oracle Data sources. It is available for SQL Server database. As I was connecting to an Oracle datasource , I do not see this  . A special mention about the YouTube channel where I got this answer .
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbi5G5PjWBaQUFy7XU_O7yw and also explanation link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/oracle-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#Query